# Uncaught Error Syntax error unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery, syntax-error

Can someone help me to resolve this error?

**JS**:

```
jQuery(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 960) {
        jQuery("#menu").append("<div id='menu-trigger' />");
    } else {
        jQuery("#menu").remove("<div id='menu-trigger' />");
    }
});
```

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div id='menu-trigger' />
```

Comment: ("#menu-trigger");?? @Anton

Comment: Is that all the javascript you have ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use:

```
jQuery("#menu-trigger").remove();
```

instead of:

```
jQuery("#menu").remove("<div id='menu-trigger' />");
```

Comment: May @Maanstraat appriciate an explanation **1/** _'remove()' method does not accept any argument_ **2/** _'remove' method "removes" nodes contained in the jQuery collection that initiated the call... At the time 'remove()' is called your jQuery collection contains "#menu" element so 'remove' would put that element out of the DOM._

Answer (score 1):

write below code :-

```
jQuery(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 960) {
        jQuery("#menu").append('<div id="menu-trigger" />');
    } else {
        jQuery("#menu-trigger").remove();    }
});
```